# Python pandas how to update a column with value 1 if another column contains a certain word

Tags: python, pandas, replace, contains

df looks like this:

| description and keybenefits (14) | brand_cooltouch (1711) | brand_easylogic (1712) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum |  |  |
| Lorem Ipsum easylogic Lorem Ipsum |  |  |
| Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum |  |  |

What I want:

- When column description and keybenefits (14) contains the value 'cooltouch' column brand_cooltouch (1711) needs to be set to value 1 (int).
- When column description and keybenefits (14) contains the value 'easylogic' column brand_easylogic (1712) needs to be set to value 1 (int).

Output that I want:

| description and keybenefits (14) | brand_cooltouch (1711) | brand_easylogic (1712) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum | 1 |  |
| Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum easylogic |  | 1 |
| Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum |  |  |

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

For the string `cooltouch` do the following

```
df['brand_cooltouch (1711)'] = df['description and keybenefits (14)'].str.contains('cooltouch', case=False).astype(int)

[Out]:

    description and keybenefits (14)  brand_cooltouch (1711)  brand_easylogic (1712)
0  Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum                       1                     None
1  Lorem Ipsum easylogic Lorem Ipsum                       0                     None
2            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum                       0                     None
```

For the string `easylogic`, do the following

```
df['brand_easylogic (1712)'] = df['description and keybenefits (14)'].str.contains('easylogic', case=False).astype(int)

[Out]:

    description and keybenefits (14)  brand_cooltouch (1711)  brand_easylogic (1712)
0  Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum                       1                     0
1  Lorem Ipsum easylogic Lorem Ipsum                       0                     1
2            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum                       0                     0
```

---

**Notes:**

- `case=False` is to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @Isabella didn't understand your goal... If the goal is to replace `None` with `0`, one might want to [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23743460/7109869).

Comment: Alternatively, if that doesn't answer your question, and assuming it doesn't exist yet, I would recommend asking a new question. Most likely you will get the needed help from the community.

Answer (score 0):

you can use np.where. I'd suggest to fill all cells where the condition is not met with NaN or 0. Here is a solution using `np.nan`

```
df["brand_cooltouch (1711)“] = np.where(df["description and keybenefits (14)“].str.contains("cooltouch"), 1, np.nan)
df["brand_easylogic (1712)“] = np.where(df["description and keybenefits (14)“].str.contains("easylogic"), 1, np.nan)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Series.str.contains` -

```py
df['brand_cooltouch (1711)'] = df['description and keybenefits (14)'].str.contains("cooltouch").astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
    description and keybenefits (14)  brand_cooltouch (1711)  brand_easylogic (1712)
0  Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum                       1                     NaN
1  Lorem Ipsum easylogic Lorem Ipsum                       0                     NaN
2            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum                       0                     NaN
```

If you do not wish the resulting column to be 1's and 0's - you could also do something like -

```py
df.loc[df['description and keybenefits (14)'].str.contains("cooltouch"), ['brand_cooltouch (1711)']] = '1'
df.loc[~df['description and keybenefits (14)'].str.contains("cooltouch"), ['brand_cooltouch (1711)']] = ''
```

**Output**

```
    description and keybenefits (14) brand_cooltouch (1711)  brand_easylogic (1712)
0  Lorem Ipsum cooltouch Lorem Ipsum                      1                     NaN
1  Lorem Ipsum easylogic Lorem Ipsum                                            NaN
2            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum                                            NaN
```